# How to use an admin react component on front-end?

Tags: keystonejs, react-day-picker

How can I re-use the admin `react-day-picker.js` component (already included in keystonejs) on a front-end form date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-day-picker` is installed as a Node module by Keystone. You can require/import it to re-use the code within that folder. You can alternatively save it as a depdency in your own project to make sure you always have it, though it isn't necessary since Keystone has it in its own `package.json`.

```
import DayPicker from "react-day-picker";

import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css"
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-day-picker

Comment: Where would I add this code on a clone of [keystone demo](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo) to add a [date range picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/?range) to the [contact form](http://demo.keystonejs.com/contact) (after adding `"react-day-picker": "^5.2.0"`, `"react": "^15.0.0"` and `"moment": "2.10.0"` to `keystone/package.json` if required)? Then how to use it in the view `keystone-demo/templates/views/contact.pug`?

Comment: I'm still learning React; I would assume that the code I posted would go in your React file for the view you're trying to render. You could include the source file directly in your Pug view and work with any React code you have there too, if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Still trying to get it to work. Adding the `import ` code to Pug view/standalone js file results in error `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`